# Android app. works in emulator but not working in android device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms, intentservice

I have written a simple application to fetch the network details where i have used an AlarmManager to continuously run a piece of code in the background(IntentServiceImpl class)..

I am invoking the AlarmManager class from the BroadcastReceiver, and i have registered the BroadcastReceiver(BroadcastReceiverImpl class) for BOOT_COMPLETE event... it is working properly in the android emulator but it is not working in Android Device(i have checked it in Samsung Galaxy s2 and Samsung Galaxy Tab)  Here is the source code..

BroadcastReceiverImpl.java

```
public class BroadcastReceiverImpl extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = BroadcastReceiverImpl.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inside the BroadcastReceiver Class");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,QOSConstants.TIME_DELAY_IN_SECONDS);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, IntentServiceImpl.class);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, QOSConstants.REQUEST_CODE,serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //After after 60 seconds
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
        QOSConstants.MILLISECONDS * QOSConstants.TIME_DELAY_IN_SECONDS, pendingIntent); 

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exiting the QOSBroadcastReceiver Class");
    }
}
```

IntentServiceImpl.java

```
public class IntentServiceImpl extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

    private String strNetworkInfo;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private QOSDatabaseHelper qosDatabaseHelper;
    private NetworkDetailsVO networkDetailsVO ;
    private static final String LOG_TAG =  QOSIntentService.class.getName();
    private QOSServlet qosServlet;
    private QOSPhoneStateListner qosPhoneStateListner;

    public QOSIntentService() {
        super(LOG_TAG);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG , ": Inside NetworkInfoService() constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        qosServlet = new QOSServlet();
        networkDetailsVO  = new NetworkDetailsVO();
        qosPhoneStateListner = new QOSPhoneStateListner();
        qosDatabaseHelper = new QOSDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i("LOG_TAG: ", "Inside onHandleIntent(Intent) method Fetching Network Details ");

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){

            String networkState = getNetworkStateString(networkInfo.getState());
            String stateString = networkInfo.toString().replace(',', '\n');
            strNetworkInfo = String.format(QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISPLAY_FORMAT,
            networkInfo.getTypeName(),networkState,stateString);

            networkDetailsVO.setNetworkState(networkState);
            networkDetailsVO.setNetworkType(networkInfo.getTypeName());
            networkDetailsVO.setRoaming(String.valueOf(networkInfo.isRoaming()));
            networkDetailsVO.setReason(networkInfo.getReason());
            networkDetailsVO.setFailOver(String.valueOf(networkInfo.isFailover()));
            networkDetailsVO.setNetworkAvailable(String.valueOf(networkInfo.isAvailable()));
            networkDetailsVO.setNetworkConnectivity(String.valueOf(networkInfo.isConnected()));

        if(networkInfo.getExtraInfo()!=null)
            networkDetailsVO.setExtraNetworkInfo(networkInfo.getExtraInfo());
            else
            networkDetailsVO.setExtraNetworkInfo(QOSConstants.NETWORK_EXTRA_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, QOSConstants.MINIMUM_TIME, QOSConstants.MINIMUM_DISTANCE, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false));

        if(location!=null){

            onLocationChanged(location);
            QOSGeocoder qosGeocoder = new QOSGeocoder();
            networkDetailsVO.setLocationAddress(qosGeocoder.getLocationAddress(getApplicationContext(), location));

        }else{

            networkDetailsVO.setLatitude(0.0);
            networkDetailsVO.setLongitude(0.0);

        }

        // Identify the connectivity type. WI-FI/MOBILE.

        if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            networkDetailsVO.setSignalStrength(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed());

        }else if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){

            telephonyManager.listen(qosPhoneStateListner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
            networkDetailsVO.setSignalStrength(qosPhoneStateListner.getStrSignalStrength());
        }

        networkDetailsVO.setNetworkInfo(strNetworkInfo);
        networkDetailsVO.setSimSerialNumber(telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
        networkDetailsVO.setOperatorName(telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());
        networkDetailsVO.setDateTime(new Date().toString());

        Log.i(LOG_TAG , "Network Details :- " + "\t" + networkInfo.toString());

        //qosDatabaseHelper = new QOSDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        qosDatabaseHelper.saveRecord(networkDetailsVO);
        qosServlet.invokeServlet(networkDetailsVO);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG , " Network details are saved to the Database,exiting onHandleIntent(Intent) method ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, " : Inside onLocationChanged(Location) method ");

        networkDetailsVO.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        networkDetailsVO.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, " : Exiting onLocationChanged(Location) method ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ": Provider is Enabled !! ");

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, QOSConstants.MINIMUM_TIME, 
                QOSConstants.SECOND_MINIMUM_DISTANCE, this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String string) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ": Provider is Disabled !! ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String strStatus, int arg1, Bundle bundle) {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, " : Inside onStatusChanged(String,int,Bundle) method ");
    }

    private String getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State state){

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ": Inside getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State)");

        String stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;

        switch(state)
        {
        case CONNECTED: 
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED;
            break;

        case CONNECTING:        
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTING;
            break;

        case DISCONNECTED:      
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTED;  
            break;

        case DISCONNECTING:     
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTING;  
            break;

        case SUSPENDED:
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_SUSPENDED;
            break;

        default: 
            stateString = QOSConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;

            break;

        }

        return stateString;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(qosDatabaseHelper!=null){
            qosDatabaseHelper.closeDatabase();
        }
    }
}



        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String string) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, ": Provider is Disabled !! ");
        }


        /*@Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            Log.i("LOG_TAG: ", "Inside onBind(Intent) method");
            return null;
        }
        */


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String strStatus, int arg1, Bundle bundle) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " : Inside onStatusChanged(String,int,Bundle) method ");
        }


        private class SignalStrengthDetector extends PhoneStateListener{


            @Override
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
                networkDetailsVO.setSignalStrength(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Signal Strength :-" + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()));

            }

        }


        private String getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State state){

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, ": Inside getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State)");

            String stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;

            switch(state)
            {
            case CONNECTED: 
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED;             
                break;

            case CONNECTING:        
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTING;    
                break;

            case DISCONNECTED:      
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTED;  
                break;

            case DISCONNECTING:     
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_DISCONNECTING;  
                break;

            case SUSPENDED:         
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_SUSPENDED;              
                break;

            default: 
                stateString = NetworkInfoConstants.NETWORK_STATE_UNKNOWN;     

                break;

            }

            return stateString;
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01.activity.QOSActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01.intentservice.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01.activity.QOSActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01.intentservice.IntentServiceImpl"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.pervazive.qualityofservice_v01.broadcastreceiver.BroadcastReceiverImpl" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please let know what is the error...please let me know where can i find the log file in Android device... (because it is running on the Android Emulator but not running i=on the Android device...) Thanks in Advance

Comment: do logcat print anything? if so please share  it.

Comment: You can get the log in Android device by installing applications like aLogcat. I think the logs can also be accessed from ADB.

Comment: Dude, you have to clean up the code, there are several duplicates.

Comment: This is the error i am getting...

**E/SpannableStringBuilder( 4806): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length**

Comment: @shoerat  please let me know the duplicates in the above code...

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your project> Android Tools> Export as signed android application. 
Fill required fields and you are good to go.